# convert SQL Reporting Services project (.rptproj) to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have an .rptproj that works with VS 2008, but I can't convert it to VS 2010

This link seems to confirm the issue but provides no options:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532664/cannot-open-a-sql-reporting-services-rptproj-file?wa=wsignin1.0

Any suggestions or new info on this?

Comment: 4 years later - link is broken. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a rather old thread, however it's one of the first ones I come across when I tried to fix this exact same issue with VS2008 rptproj files. 
I've found a solution that worked perfectly, and it came from here: [Are SSRS Reports supported in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333459/do-ssrs-reports-support-localization-resources-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2012)

Here's the copy/paste of the instructions, which I modified only in that I used SQL Express fine:

**I got reports and a report project (.rtproj) to work in Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2008 R2!** It will presumably work in any combination of VS 2010/2012 with SQL Server 2008 (R2) or SQL Server 2012.

1. Install Visual Studio 2010 PLUS SP1.
2. Install [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (SSDT)
3. Install SQL Server 2012 with Data Tools and Reporting Services. (I used the Express version)

Now I can use Visual Studio 2010 for editing and deploying reports, even to SQL Server 2008 R2 (and likely other versions).

*For older SQL Server Reporting Service versions there is still a question of whether there is anything new or unsupported in the VS10/12 report editor project.*

Answer (score 5):

Not gonna happen... any time soon

http://lwoodyiii.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/reporting-services-projects-in-vs-2010/

Answer (score 3):

> You must install either Visual Studio
>   2008 or SQL Server 2008 Business
>   Intelligence Design Studio and use
>   that to directly open a Report Server
>   project, bypassing any solution file
>   that previously included the report
>   project. You can continue to use
>   Visual 2010 for the rest of your
>   solution.

-Taken from https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532664/cannot-open-a-sql-reporting-services-rptproj-file?wa=wsignin1.0