# Are SSRS Reports supported in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2012

I haven't seen anything in the [release notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960138.aspx), has anyone determined if there has been any improvement in this area? It's kind of surprising MS wouldn't support `.resx` files out of the box for SSRS reports.

The only option I see is creating a separate class library and using it to retrieve resource strings as shown in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriram_reddy1/archive/2012/01/09/localization-in-ssrs-reports.aspx), which doesn't mention which version of SQL Server or VS they are using. (relating to the original question, it changed into just getting reports working in vs 2012)

I tried the **Visual Studio 2012 Pro** trial and the migration of the report project failed.

> ProjectName.rptproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found.

When the project opens in Visual studio 2012 the Report Project says `(incompatible)` and text below it says

> This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I got reports and a report project (.rtproj) to work in Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2008 R2**! It will presumably work in any combination of VS 2010/2012 with SQL Server 2008 (R2) or SQL Server 2012.

1. Install Visual Studio 2010 PLUS SP1.
2. Install [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (SSDT)
3. Install SQL Server 2012 with Data Tools and Reporting Services. (I used the trial version)

Now I can use Visual Studio 2010 for editing and deploying reports, even to SQL Server 2008 R2 (and likely other versions).

*For older SQL Server Reporting Service versions there is still a question of whether there is anything new or unsupported in the VS10/12 report editor project.*

Comment: Iko, Did you have to install SQL Server 2012 with Data Tools and Reporting Services on the client machine that is running visual studio?

Comment: Yes, the 3 items listed were installed on the developers own PC(s). The reports can then be deployed to e.g. a production server which is using SQL Server 2008 R2 (with Business Intelligence etc. setup separately). After setting up the server with 2008 SS R2 & business intelligence it didn't need any changes upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010, the only changes were on the developers PCs to get VS to allow report editing.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the same tools enable SSIS package development as well?

Comment: @jay enable SSI package finally ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e495eb69-a0a4-4140-8f57-7ba25f2901b0/use-rptproj-ssrs-for-sql-server-2008r2-in-vs-2010-andor-vs-2012-better?forum=sqlreportingservices&prof=required **SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012** supports versions of SQL Server 2012 or lower, download **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012**, then select _SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012_ and _SQL Client Connectivity SDK_ as new shard features to install

Comment: We can open the projects in both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010. For local mode only (that is, when not connected to SQL Server), we won’t get the design-time experience for controls that are associated with the viewer in Visual Studio 2008, but the project will function correctly at runtime. If we add a feature that’s specific to Visual Studio 2012, the report schema is upgraded automatically and you can no longer open the project in Visual Studio 2008.